# Network manager command line script

Tags: networking, scripting

As RHEL boots up and I login, I'd want to manually run a script which would:

1. Identify the active ethernet interface (the eth ID being used).
2. Ask for, and would let me type the IP address, netmask, gateway and
   DNS servers, and save that info to the active ethernet interface
   settings.

I can do all this manually through the NM interface but wondering if it is possible through nmcli, and, if so, how?

Comment: It sounds like you need to read the `nmcli` documentation. Start with `man nmcli`, `nmcli help`, and `nmcli general help`, then head to google. No need to ask SE how to do something that is explained in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have spent some time reading through the documentation of nmcli. I am not a programmer so perhaps I should read up on how to prompt for input entries which could be saved into NM. I also wanted to check here to make sure that I am looking at the right direction when I concentrate on nmcli?

Comment: Read more documentation on `nmcli` and writing beginner bash scripts, you should be able to figure this out within a day.